# Get variable type name

Tags: c++

I got 2 classes that are using templates with 2 arguments, MinHeap and HeapNode. I create a MinHeap object in the main that creates a vector inside the class and after that I call insert function that inserts a HeapNode in the MinHeap vector.

The problem appears when in insert method I can't create a HeapNode because the variable types are not caught by the compiler  giving me that error:

type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template class HeapNode’ Heap.push_back(HeapNode(key,value));

Main code:

```
MinHeap<int,string> vector(); 
vector.insert(2,"Hola");
```

Insert function code:

```
void MinHeap<T,V>::insert(T key, V value){ 
Heap.push_back(HeapNode<typeid(key).name(),typeid(value).name()>       
(key,value));
}
```

HeapNode class code:

```
#ifndef HEAPNODE_H
#define HEAPNODE_H
template <class T, class V>
class HeapNode {
public:
HeapNode(T newKey, V newValue);
HeapNode(const HeapNode& orig);
virtual ~HeapNode();
T getKey();
void setKey(T newKey);
V getValue();
void setValue(V newValue);
private:
T key;
V value;

};

template <class T, class V>
HeapNode<T,V>::HeapNode(T newKey, V newValue){
this->key = newKey;
this->value = newValue;
}

template <class T, class V>
T HeapNode<T,V>::getKey(){
 return key;
}

template <class T, class V>
void HeapNode<T,V>::setKey(T newKey){
this->key = newKey;
}

template <class T, class V>
V HeapNode<T,V>::getValue(){
return value;

}
template <class T, class V>
void HeapNode<T,V>::setValue(V newValue){
this->value = newValue;
}
#endif /* HEAPNODE_H */
```

MinHeap class code:

```
#ifndef MINHEAP_H
#define MINHEAP_H
#include "HeapNode.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template <class T, class V>
class MinHeap {
public:
    MinHeap();
    MinHeap(const MinHeap& orig);
    virtual ~MinHeap();
    T size();
    T empty();
    void insert(T key,V value);
    T min();
    T minValues();
    void removeMin();
    void printHeap();
    void removeMinAux(T i);

private:
    std::vector<T,V> Heap;
    void swap(HeapNode<T,V>* parent, HeapNode<T,V>* child);

};

/*
template <class T, class V>
MinHeap<T,V>::~MinHeap(){
    delete Heap;
}*/
template <class T, class V>
void MinHeap<T,V>::insert(T key, V value){ 
    Heap.push_back(HeapNode<typeid(key).name(),typeid(value).name()>(key,value));
}
template <class T, class V>
T MinHeap<T,V>::empty(){
    return Heap.empty();
}
template <class T, class V>
T MinHeap<T,V>::size(){
    return Heap.size();
}
template <class T, class V>
T MinHeap<T,V>::min(){
    return Heap.front().getKey();
}

template <class T, class V>
T MinHeap<T,V>::minValues(){
    return Heap.front().getValue();
}

template <class T, class V>
void MinHeap<T,V>::removeMin(){
    Heap.front() = Heap.back();
    Heap.pop_back();
    removeMinAux(0);
}

template <class T, class V>
void MinHeap<T,V>::removeMinAux(T i){
    if(Heap.at(i*2+1)== 0){
       cout<< "Heap has been reordenated"<<endl; 
    }else{
        if(Heap.at(i*2+1).getKey()<Heap.at(i*2+2).getKey()){
            swap(Heap.at(i*2+1),Heap.at(i));
            removeMinAux(i*2+1);
        }else{
            swap(Heap.at(i*2+2),Heap.at(i));
            removeMinAux(i*2+2);
        }
    }


}
template <class T, class V>
void MinHeap<T,V>::swap(HeapNode<T,V>* parent, HeapNode<T,V>* child){
    T tmp; 
    tmp = *child;
    *child = *parent;
    *parent = tmp; 
    delete tmp; 

}





#endif /* MINHEAP_H */


                                                                ^
```

Comment: Code and question indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of the [typeid operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

Comment: MinHeap<int,string> vector();  seems wrong, it's not vector - without the parenthesis?

Comment: If your question has been answered satisfactorily, it would be nice for you to mark the answer as "accepted", and upvote if you found it particularly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problems with your code run a bit deep, unfortunately.

Your main code creates a min heap instance like this:

```
MinHeap<int,string> vector();
```

This wouldn't build for me; a new version of visual studio and an old version of GCC both rejected it with various complaints (are you aware of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), as an example of how this sort of thing can trip you up?) I changed it to

```
MinHeap<int, string> v;
```

This constructs a `MinHeap` instance with a private member `Heap` that effectively looks like this:

```
std::vector<int,string> Heap;
```

Now, if you look at the docs for [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you'll see that what you're doing here is creating a vector of `int` with an *allocator* of `string`. This isn't ever going to work, and you're certainly not going to be able to push `HeapNode` instances onto it!

What you should have done is this:

```
std::vector<HeapNode<T, V>> Heap;
```

Now, in your insert function, you do this:

```
Heap.push_back(HeapNode<typeid(key).name(),typeid(value).name()> (key,value));
```

Which is, as IInspectable says above, a fundamental misunderstanding of how the typeid operator works, and also a misunderstanding of how template types work. `typeid(foo).name()` is the *name* of a type, not the *actual* type itself. That's why your error message says "type/value mismatch".

You already know the type of `key` and the type of `value`... they're right there in the function prototype! `T` and `V` respectively!

If you do this:

```
Heap.push_back(HeapNode<T,V>(key,value));
```

The problem goes away. There may be more problems, but as you haven't defined all the functionality of `HeapNode` and `MinHeap` in your supplied code, there's not much I can do about those.

Comment: (but yes, `using namespace std` is discouraged even before people do terrible things like calling stuff `vector`)